# MinecraftEdu shows that the server is 1.7.10 while the Mod that I made is 1.8, is that the reason why it doesn't read the Mod?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I coded my Minecraft Mod and it is a 1.8 Mod, and then I got MinecraftEdu and I wanted to install my Mod in MinecraftEdu, so I put it in both the server and the client mods folder. But it doesn't work, I mean the Mod is not even read or recognised. Do you think the problem is because of versions difference?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Mods are specific to the major version, so a 1.8 mod will not automatically work in a 1.7.10 system. You might be able to port it easily, depending on the particular aspects of the mod.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)